# Calculate wavelet coefficients with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wavelet-analysis

Let $\operatorname{rect}(x)$ be a constant function equal to 1 with support $[-1 / 2,1 / 2]$. Define a step function using the sequence as
$$    f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^4 a_k \operatorname{rect}(x-k)$$
where $a_1=10$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=\frac12$ and $a_4=\frac14$. The Haar function is defined by
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:haar}
\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
  1 \quad & 0 \leq  x < \frac{1}{2},\\
 -1 & \frac{1}{2} \leq x < 1,\\
  0 &\mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The family of functions $\mathcal{F}=\lbrace\psi_{j,n}\rbrace_{j,n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, where $\psi_{j,n}(x) = 2^{j / 2} \psi(2^j x-n)$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a wavelet system.

The wavelet coefficients are
$$w_{j,n}=\left\langle f, \psi_{j, n}\right\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \psi_{j, n}(x) d x$$
I would like to write a code in Mathematica to calculate the coefficients $w_{j,n}$ and check the correctness of the results I got by hand for them. For me the real problem here is defining step functions in Mathematica... any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The a step function from -1/2 to 1/2  may be declared as:

```
rect[x_] = UnitStep[x + 1/2] - UnitStep[x - 1/2];
Plot[rect[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

And your step function f:

```
a[1] = 10; a[2] = 1; a[3] = 1/2; a[4] = 1/4;
f[x_] = Sum[a[i] rect[x - i], {i, 1, 4}];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I can't to represent in Mathematica the functions $\psi_{j,n}$.

Comment: Look up in the help: "guide/Wavelets" and "tutorial/DefiningYourOwnWavelet"